# MatPlotLib не полностью выводит гистограмму с русскими названиями на оси OX

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

при использовании МатПлотЛиб появилась проблем:
Подается два списка для гистограммы bar: первый - список с именами хоккейных команд, второй - с забитыми шайбами.

```
def to_hist(): # Создание гистограммы
   print(games_history[0])
   print(len(games_history[0]) == len(games_history[1]))
   print(games_history[1])
   fig, axes = plt.subplots()
   plt.bar(games_history[0], games_history[1])
   fig.set_figwidth(13)
   fig.set_figheight(8)
   fig.suptitle("Количество забитых сопернику шайб клубом " + team + ". " + "Сезон " + seazon)
   games_history[0] = axes.set_xticklabels(games_history[0], fontsize = 12, rotation = 90, verticalalignment = 'top', horizontalalignment='right')
                                      # Рзамер шривта, поворот текста, вертикальное и горизонтальное выравнивание
   axes.set_xlabel('Клубы-соперники')
   axes.set_ylabel('Количество забитых шайб сопернику')
   rects = axes.patches # Загрузка патчей
   for r, score in zip(rects, games_history[1]): 
      height = r.get_height()
      axes.text(r.get_x() + r.get_width() / 2, height + 1, score, ha='center', va='bottom', color='#000')
   plt.show()
```

Длина массивов одинаковая. Должно быть больше 50. а выводит 27. Причем, если делать строки не русскими буквами, то всё выводит правильно.
Вот примеры этих массивов (изображение для них):

```
['Локомотив', 'Атлант', 'СКА', 'Северсталь', 'Автомобилист', 'Барыс', 'Авангард', 'Медвешчак', 'Донбасс', 'Спартак', 'Динамо Мн', 'Ак Барс', 'Торпедо НН', 'Витязь', 'ОХК Динамо М', 'Адмирал', 'Амур', 'Металлург Нк', 'Сибирь', 'Нефтехимик', 'Салават Юлаев', 'Металлург Мг', 'Трактор', 'Слован', 'Лев Пр', 'Динамо Р', 'ЦСКА', 'Слован', 'Лев Пр', 'Динамо Р', 'ЦСКА', 'Нефтехимик', 'Салават Юлаев', 'Металлург Мг', 'Трактор', 'Адмирал', 'Амур', 'Металлург Нк', 'Сибирь', 'Ак Барс', 'Торпедо НН', 'Витязь', 'ОХК Динамо М', 'Динамо Мн', 'Донбасс', 'Медвешчак', 'Спартак', 'Авангард', 'Автомобилист', 'Барыс', 
'Северсталь', 'Локомотив', 'Атлант', 'СКА']
True
[2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 6, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

[image: Гистограмма]

Большое спасибо заранее!

Comment: Для начала исправьте свой вопрос. Похоже вы его разметили, но даже не удосужились взглянуть как это у вас получилось.

Comment: Может просто окно увеличить?

Comment: @Victor VosMottor thanks Monica - Вы внесли некоторое исправление в вопрос. И сразу породили два дополнительных вопроса.1 Откуда вы знаете, что "Причем, если делать строки не русскими буквами, то всё выводит правильно." и 2. Вы можете привести фрагмент программы, подтверждающий этот тезис?

Comment: @passant "Причем, если делать строки не русскими буквами, то всё выводит правильно." — где я это сказал?

Comment: @Victor VosMottor thanks Monica Если не вы -  приношу извинения.  Просто мне высветило, что вопрос был измен вами.  Возможно я не правильно понял информацию.  Если не вы- то вопрос к тому, кто эту фразу добавил.

Comment: @passant [так и было](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1151936/revisions)

Answer (score 2):

Это не проблема Matplotlib.

У вас в списке команд ровно 27  уникальных команд. Вот он вам их и выводит. А как вы хотели, что-бы он выводил вам bar-график??